# How to add inline @change or @update function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Here is my code snippet.

```
<template>
   <b-form-input
     type="text"
     name="title"
     class="form-control"
     placeholder="Post Title"
     @update="onUpdate"
    />
</template>

<script>
 export default{
   methods:{
      onUpdate(value) {
        console.log(value)
      }
   }
 }
</script>
```

While I was trying to make the update function inline something like this:

```
<b-form-input
     type="text"
     name="title"
     class="form-control"
     placeholder="Post Title"
     @update="()=>{console.log(value)}"      //which is wrong
/>
```

What will be correct format ? Thanks in advance!

*CodeSandbox Playground:* https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-benz-w8wgu?file=/src/FormFields.vue

Comment: try //@change or @input

Comment: consider a case where @update is mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline functions, but the expressions are evaluated in the context of the Vue instance.  What you tried would work except that `console` isn't a property of the Vue instance.  But you can add the `console.log` method to your component's methods if you like:

```html
@update="()=>{ log(value) }"
```

```js
methods: {
  log: console.log
}
```

If you wanted to use the `console.log` syntax explicitly like that, you'd have to add `console` to data:

```html
@update="()=>{ console.log(value) }"
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    console: console    // just `console` would work too
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I need to add any custom function like: @update="($event) => setField(value, "title")"  ? how to do so ?

Comment: There is no need to do that.  It's the same as `@update="setField(value, 'title')"`.  You can already set a method to the handler.  If `setField` isn't a method, add it the same way as I showed adding `console.log` to methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct to use an inline handler and its handler parameter represents the typed value :

```
<b-form-input
     type="text"
     name="title"
     class="form-control"
     placeholder="Post Title"
     @update="($event)=>{console.log($event)}"    
/>

....
  created() {
    this.console = window.console;
  },
```

Comment: It's throwing "[Vue warn]: Property or method "console" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."

Comment: Here is the CodeSandbox playground :  https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-benz-w8wgu?file=/src/FormFields.vue

Comment: try out `@update="($event)=>{window.console.log($event)}" `

Comment: Still it's throwing error. I updated the sandbox example as your suggested method

Comment: please check my edited answer and this sample https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-glitter-qo1q2?file=/src/FormFields.vue

Comment: Thanks ! final asking..what if i need to add any custom function like: ```@update="($event) => setField(value, "title")" ``` ? how to do so ?

Comment: You could do `@update="($event) => setField($event, "title")"`